# How to make Tailwind @layer components responsive?

Tags: responsive, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

How do I specify the desktop version of a Tailwind @layer component class in a div?
Below doesn't seem to work, it shows mobile version independent of breakpoint in Chrome:

```
    <button type="button" class="my-button md:my-button-desktop">Click here
    </button>
```

main.scss below:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .my-button {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 130%;
    color: theme("colors.white");
    background-color: theme("colors.btnDefault");
    border:solid;
    border-color: theme("colors.primaryColor100");
    border-width: 0.1rem;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
.my-button-desktop {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: theme("colors.white");
    background-color: theme("colors.btnDefault");
    border:solid;
    border-color: theme("colors.primaryColor100");
    border-width: 0.2rem;
    padding-top: 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're able to use default CSS @media rules within your main.scss, so simply amend it to change the .my-button class when at a minimum width:

```
@layer components {
  .my-button {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 130%;
    color: theme("colors.white");
    background-color: theme("colors.btnDefault");
    border: solid;
    border-color: theme("colors.primaryColor100");
    border-width: 0.1rem;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .my-button {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 150%;
      color: theme("colors.white");
      background-color: theme("colors.btnDefault");
      border: solid;
      border-color: theme("colors.primaryColor100");
      border-width: 0.2rem;
      padding-top: 0.7rem;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
}
```

and then all you have to do is remove the `md:my-button-desktop` from your button tag.

Comment: This works, but it's not the "Tailwind way" of doing it. But if the Tailwind way is not possible in this case, then I can mark this solution as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the recommended way for this is to use breakpoint-prefixed rules to target specific viewport widths rather than using `@media` or Tailwind's `screen` function:

```css
@layer components {
  .my-button {
    /* mobile defaults */
    @apply text-sm;
    @apply font-thin;
    /* and so on... */
    
    /* desktop overrides */
    @apply lg:text-sm;
    @apply lg:font-normal;
    /* and so on... */
  }
}
```

If you have specific rules that you want to apply that aren't offered by Tailwind by default, you'll likely have to add your own custom rules then.  Hope this helps in some way!